# How to send task to exchange rather then queue in celery python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

What I understood from celery's documentations, when publishing tasks, you send them to exchange first and then exchange delegates it to queues. Now I want to send a task to specific custom made exchange which will delegate all tasks it receives to 3 different queues, which will have different consumers in the background, performing different tasks.

```
class Tasks(object):

    def __init__(self, config_object={}):
        self.celery = Celery()
        self.celery.config_from_object(config_object)
        self.task_publisher = task_publisher

    def publish(self, task_name, job_id=None, params={}):

        if not job_id:
        job_id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.celery.send_task(task_name, [job_id, params], queue='new_queue')

class config_object(object):

    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
    BROKER_PORT = 5672
    BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'

tasks_service = Tasks(config_object)
tasks_service.publish('logger.log_event', params={'a': 'b'})
```

This is how I can send a task to specific queue, if I Dont define the queue it gets sent to a default one, but my question is how do I define the exchange to send to?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have solved this problem.
i came across the same thing last week.
I am on Celery 4.1 and the solution I came up with was to just define the exchange name and the routing_key

so in your publish method, you would do something like:

```
    def publish(self, task_name, job_id=None, params={}):

        if not job_id:
            job_id = uuid.uuid4()
            self.celery.send_task(
                task_name,
                [job_id, params],
                exchange='name.of.exchange',
                routing_key='*'
            )
```